# Entering property where no one lives when your sports item went there?

Tags: halal-haram, property

My cricket bowl went into the house which is empty so what i do

Answer (score 2):

Contact the owners of the house even if no one lives there it is probably owned by someone.

> If you find no one at home, do not enter it until you have been given
> permission. And if you are asked to leave, then leave. That is purer
> for you. And Allah has ˹perfect˺ knowledge of what you do.
>
> https://quran.com/24/28

Otherwise buy a new cricket ball and stop playing near houses go find a proper playground.

Answer (score 1):

> There is no blame upon you for entering houses not inhabited in which
> there is convenience for you. And Allāh knows what you reveal and what
> you conceal. [Quran 24:29](https://quran.com/an-nur/29)